# Why can't I pass INT ++ in a function parameter, but I can pass INT + 1 in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the reason why Index++ does not increment the value when passed to a function? I'm using AngularJS V1.6.6 and Index + 1 works, but Index++ does not.

I have a recursive function, taking an array and index as parameters. In order to increment the index on the recursive call, I was calling:

`recursiveFunction(List, Index++);`

No errors were thrown on the call itself, but a maximum call stack size exceeded error was thrown since the index never changed. Alternatively if I call:

`recursiveFunction(List, Index + 1);`

instead, the function works fine and increments the index properly. Another solution that works is:

```
Index++;
recursiveFunction(List, Index);
```

Comment: Why would you want a post-call increment operation? `f(x + 1)` and `f(x++)` are two *very* different things.

Comment: `index++` returns the old value, then increments the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that `i++` is not the same as `++i` or `i + 1`.

`i++` uses the value of i and **THEN** increments `i`.

`++i` on the other hand increments `i` and uses the value **AFTER**. So `++i` is equal to `i + 1`.

```js
let a = 10;
console.log(a++); // => 10

let b = 10;
console.log(++b); // => 11
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment).